# Selecting one item in multi select list view selects many items

Tags: android, android-contacts, listactivity

I am trying to make a contact picker with multiple selection. I am able to load all the contacts with check boxes next to them. However, when I select an item, every 8th item gets selected automatically in my list. Moreover, when I scroll up and down all the selections get changed by itself.

Anybody know what's wrong with this? Here is my contact picker class

```
public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1},0);

        setListAdapter(adapter);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
        CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;
        textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the views recycling mechanism in the `ListView`. Try adding the following in you `onCreate()`.

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```